A sudden jump of votes
Is it statistically possible that a candidate's votes jumps from 48% to 54% while the last 10% of votes are counted?
It may be possible theoretically, but would require a situation where people from one side of a country have extremely different opinions from the rest of the country. I'm not sure that such a difference could exist in reality without the country being torn by civil war.

Is this a purely hypothetical question, or based on a specific example?

If this is about the revecent Moldova elections, the 48% to 54% is true, but the 'jump' was over the last 50% not over the last 10% of the remaining votes to be counted.

I think this question is missing some important context. It starts as a math question and ends with civil war. Please include more details about what you think is the core problem in the question.

The nature of picking one candidate to vote for is that it makes differences appear more extreme than perhaps they really are. If my whole town is united in thinking that B is a decent candidate but A is significantly better, we're likely to vote strongly in favor of A, but that doesn't mean we're in a civil war with the B supporters.

You need to include all relevant details including which election this is about.

You use 2 very different terms:  votes in the title, rating in the body.  Which is it?  The answers would be vastly different.

@264champagnebottlesonice At 81% of counted ballots Sandu had 48,48%. At 92,25% she had 50,12%. At 98,65% - 54,95%. And finally at 100% - 55,35%. They provide no timeline so these numbers are from random screenshots in the Net.

There's nothing statistical about this.  If you could simply make up numbers that achieve this outcome, it's possible.  If you can't, it's not.

If a candidate has 48% of the first 90% of votes to be counted, that is 43.2% of the total votes. Thus even if that candidate receives all of the remaining 10% of total votes, that only gets them to 53.2%, short of 54%.
When assessing cases with slightly less extreme numbers it is important to remember that votes are not counted in random order. A batch of votes from a large city or from a very remote rural district can easily make the count jump starkly for one candidate or another.

Another case was mail-in votes where one of the candidates asked their supporters to vote in person if possible.

In the later/actual example provide by the OP in a comment, the 48.5% was at 81%. That's only 39.27% of the vote, with 19% remaining. If the remaining votes were all for the same leading candidate, she could have reached 58.27%.

The biggest jump they pointed out was actually at 92.25%, where she had 50.12%. That put the max she could have gotten thereafter still at 57.87%. From media reports, the "diaspora" (i.e. voting sections abroad, which get counted last) voted some 82% for her. https://www.latimes.com/world-nation/story/2024-11-04/moldovas-diaspora-tipped-the-scales-in-pivotal-presidential-election-runoff That's pretty compatible with the final result as it would yield 56.47% at that point.

@DavidHammen Why would you compute 100 - 43.2 here?

@Arno Because it's 4:21 AM and I'm not fully awake. Comment deleted. Unfortunately, I cannot retract my downvote.


Is it statistically possible that a candidate's rating jumps from 48% to 54% while the last 10% of votes are counted?

If those 10% of uncounted votes are randomly chosen, then it is extremely unlikely. In fact, even a small sample of randomly chosen votes give high confidence.
But typically the order in which votes are counted and reported is not random. Votes are usually grouped by geographic location, and sometimes by voting method. For example, rural districts with small polling places usually report votes earlier than large cities that have more votes to count. Mail-in votes may be counted separately. Votes of citizens who reside abroad are often counted last. In countries with multiple time zones, western regions mechanically stop voting later than eastern regions.

It may be possible theoretically, but would require a situation where people from one side of a country have extremely different opinions from the rest of the country. I'm not sure that such a difference could exist in reality without the country being torn by civil war.

Quite the contrary, geographical disparities are very common. For example, consider the repartition of votes by states in the 2020 presidential election in the United States. The share of votes for Biden ranged from from 26.55% in Wyoming (and even 22.34% in one of the Nebraska districts) to 66.09% in Vermont (92.15% in DC). The US have a peculiar way of electing a president, where each state (or district) votes as a whole for one candidate. When votes are counted, each time a state is called, the winning candidate's electoral vote total makes a sudden increase.
There are huge differences within states as well. For example, consider the 2000 US presidential election in Florida, county by county. The share of votes for Bush ranged from 30.93% in Broward county to 73.69% in Okaloosa county. The election result in Florida was extremely close, and Florida was the last state to be determined. The overall election was also close, and Florida was the determining state — whichever of Bush or Gore won Florida would win the election. Ultimately, Bush was declared the winner by 537 votes. This election is especially noteworthy because there were far more than 537 contested votes, and courts sympathetic to Bush blocked recounts, which made Bush the winner. If the contested votes had been uniformly distributed among voters, it would have been very likely that the contested votes would be almost half for Bush and half for Gore, like the overall voting total. However, there were a lot more contested votes in  districts that were favorable to Gore. Later an independent recount showed that Gore had in fact won by 60 to 171 votes (depending on exactly which criteria were used to determine valid votes, providing that the criteria were applied uniformly). This shows that in practice, you cannot extrapolate missing votes by assuming that they're the same as the overall result.
The United States are by no means unique in having major electoral disparities. It is very common to have significant differences between urban and rural voters, with urban voters being more educated, more open and less conservative, and especially less prone to voting for extremes. Since densely populated regions tend to take longer to count votes, they usually report last, which means that later votes can significantly swing results towards the center or towards the left.
To give another example, consider the second round of the 2022 presidential election in France. Nationally, Macron (center-right) won against Le Pen (extreme right) with 58.55% of the votes. The share of votes for Macron by département (a département is on average about 1% of the country) ranged from 40.09% in Aisne to 85.11% in Paris. All municipalities with at least 100,000 inhabitants had a majority for Macron except for the two that are overseas. In France, rural areas vote until 18:00 while large cities vote until 20:00. With only the votes that can be counted at 18:00, I think Macron would still have won, but by a much thinner margin. No one who knows anything about French politics would try to call the election by just adding the votes that are already counted before 20:00. Instead, estimates are made by taking somewhat representative samples from areas that are known to be closer to the national average.

"The United States are by no means unique in having major electoral disparities." – I live in a city which has both six universities as well as the two highest courts in our country and the federal prosecutor. As a result, there are a ton of very young, very liberal students without a lot of money, and a ton of rich old conservative lawyers and judges. The results for the Green Party, for example, differ by as much as a factor of 10x depending on whether the neighborhood is dominated by cheaper flats or more expensive houses. In some cases, there are 3x differences in neighboring streets.


Is it statistically possible that a candidate's rating jump from 48% to 54% while the last 10% of votes are counted?

Welcome to part of the reason Trump's 2020 "stolen election" narrative had legs with some of his base. A similar thing has happened elsewhere in the US. The reasons for the abnormal jump were

Slower counting of absentee/mail-in ballots
A higher propensity for those people to vote Democrat (partially because Trump had told his voters to only vote in-person)

In-person votes got counted faster, then the slower absentee counts caught up, erasing what looked to be a win for Trump

With President Donald Trump leading Joe Biden by 196,000 votes and 12 percent of the estimated vote still uncounted, Pennsylvania Democrats and Republicans spent Wednesday working out the rough math surrounding the as-yet-uncounted mail-in ballots.
There were more than 1 million mail ballots left to be counted as of 2:35 p.m., according to Pennsylvania’s Department of State. So far, 78 percent of mail ballots have broken for Biden and 21 percent have been won by Trump.

Biden went on to win Pennsylvania. In other words, it is possible, but only in certain circumstances.

There's even a name for this in the context of US politics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_shift_(politics)
